# Entity framework 5 using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am using EF5.0 i need to use a stored procd where the columns are not known till runtime (using pivot in sp query) so columns are dynamically created.I want to call this using context. Can the EF5.0 create the complex type model type automatically on runtime.Is there any other way to do it.

Thanks in advance